Best set up for rigging a linked mechanism
I am new to rigging and need help with a set up. I have the following mechanism:

A is representing a fixed motor to which an arm is attached. C represents a fixed point around which another arm ('Bone - right arm') can rotate. The motor arm is connected to the 'Bone - right arm' through 'Bone - left arm'. When the motor rotates the motor arm will move as highlighted in blue around point A. Since C is fixed this will move the point B back and forth, highlighted by the red arrows.
I was able to achieve this by adding a IK constraint to C and then keyframing A's rotation. The issue is that when A reaches around 180 degree rotation the entire mechanism snaps and almost flips on the x axis. I understand this is happening because of the IK constraint but I can't figure out a way to solve for it. This may also not be the best set up to achieve the kind of motion I want. If there's a way I can fix 'None - right arm' to C and keep it connected to 'Bone - left arm' I should be able to achieve the motion without using IK but I can't figure it out. Thanks.

Which of AB and BC can stretch?

The correct setup for this kind of movements is to use IK in this way:
IK target is child of Rotor.
IK2 has the IK constraint, targeting IK Target, with chain lenght = 2.
Make sure that Rotor is unparented from any of the two IK bones.


Thanks so much!
